# install python node with colcon

Tags: ros, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,

I'm developing a simple python node for autoware.ai, so during development I had my catkin workspace folder and to install everything I just used catkin_make command.

Here the folder structure of the node:

```
node_name/
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── README.md
├── launch
│   └── node_launchfile.launch
├── nodes
│   └── node_name_node.py
├── package.xml
├── setup.py
└── src
    └── node_name
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── package_1
        ├── package_2
        ├── package_3
        └── package_n
```

The content of setup.py is:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from catkin_pkg.python_setup import generate_distutils_setup

d = generate_distutils_setup(packages=['node_name'],
                             package_dir={'': 'src'})
```

CMakeLists.txt contains the python stuff:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
    rospy
    std_msgs
    autoware_msgs
)
catkin_python_setup()
...
catkin_install_python(PROGRAMS
    nodes/node_name_node.py
    DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)
```

Now I'm trying to use colcon to build/install the node using:

```
colcon build --cmake-clean-cache --packages-up-to node_name
```

But when I run the node then I get:

```
[ERROR] [1596211499.485229]: Error loading the module package_1:
No module named node_name.package_1
```

So it seems like that the packages are not installed. Anyone can give me some help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/358442/install-python-node-with-colcon/) by [luca.fancellu](https://answers.ros.org/users/53590/luca.fancellu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2020-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your setup file explicitly only installs the module `node_name` - but not any of the submodules.

Instead of explicitly enumerating all submodules you probably want to use `setuptools.find_packages()` to discover all Python modules automatically and pass them to the `packages` keyword argument.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2020-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [luca.fancellu](https://answers.ros.org/users/53590/luca.fancellu/) on 2020-08-03**:
I'm sure that it works, but I end up listing the packages and package dirs by hand and it worked. Thank you for your support

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2020-08-03**:
Please mark the answer with the check mark on the left of it as answered if it did answer your question.